# Find all the homomorphisms from $S_n \to Z_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Note- $m$ is even.

My attempt: I have shown the kernel of the homomorphisms will contain

1. elements of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$
2. Also the elements which can be written as a disjoint cycle of the form $(ab)(cd)$, then it will belong to the kernel of the homomorphism
3. The elements of the form $(ab)(bc)$ will also belong to the kernel of the homorphism .So all the even permutations will go to an element of order $0$ ( or the kernel)
4. Now I know, by finding the normal subgroup ,that all the odd permutations will go to an element of order $2$ and all the even permutations will go to the element of order $0$.Now my professor has advised me not to find the kernel first and calculate the homomorphism and to use the idea of $A_n$ since it has not been taught in class.

Thus the only option which is left for me is to show that $\varphi(12) \to a$ an element of order $2$ in $Z_m$, Then $\varphi(13) \to (b)$ where $b$ can be any other element of order $2$ .Then $\varphi(132) \to a+b$ where $(a+b)$ is an element of order $0$ which can hold true if $b=m-a$ like $2$ and $4$ in $Z_6$ .How do I come to a contradiction and show that it is not possible.and all the $2$ cycles will go the same element $a$ ..

Comment: I often wonder what is the point of "do not use this or that"? There is a simple, elegant solution due to the fact that $A_n$ is the only nontrivial, proper subgroup of $S_n$ (for $n\geq 5$) and the quotient is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. What would be the point of "try do it via hard (most likely equivalent) way"?

Comment: @freakish well sometimes invoking results not tought in class can make your life ALOT easier, but I get your point. Moreover, did you mean to say *normal* subgroup? I think any transposition yields a nontrivial proper subgroup ($\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ of $S_n$ for $n\geq 3$...

Comment: @PrudiiArca yes, I meant "normal".